# JQueryMobile DatePicker, how to show datepicker on textbox onfocus

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, android-datepicker

**What am I trying to do?**

Have the jqueryMobile datepicker (flip style) show the datepicker when the user clicks on the date textbox, but I cant seam to behaving the way I like.

The simple flip style date picker can be found here http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/flip/

The behavior I am aiming for is like the one that is located here
http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/demo.html

**What I need help with?**

Creating the jquery code, to make the first link's date picker (JQueryMobile), behave as the second one. (mobipick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `noButtonFocusMode` to `true` in `options`

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
   data-options='{"mode": "flipbox","noButtonFocusMode": true}'>
```

Comment: That sure did the trick, but how did you know it had that attribute, I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Especially not knowing the exact name ("nobuttonFocusmode") to search for? Is there a good reference some where, that someone can recommend?

Comment: I had used it in one of my applications..You can refer this link for all information regarding datebox - http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/